# Why is my CSS not showing changes in my HTML page

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

Here is my stylesheet.css code. It is not working when I am running my page. I have checked for the link as well .`<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">`

It is not working when I write the type as well.

```css
/* Style the header with a grey background and some padding */

    .header {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 20px 10px;
      }
      
      /* Style the header links */
      .header a {
        float: left;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 25px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
    
      .styled-table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin: 25px 0;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        min-width: 400px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
    .styled-table thead tr {
      background-color: #009879;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .styled-table th,
    .styled-table td {
        padding: 12px 15px;
    }
    .styled-table tbody tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }
    
    .styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
    }
    
    .styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #009879;
    }
    .styled-table tbody tr.active-row {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #009879;
    }
```

Comment: One possibility is that it is cached in your browser. You could try clearing the cache, or use a cache-busting technique such as changing the URL in the link tag to something like `stylesheet.css?v1`

Comment: USe Developer Tools to see where the computed style is coming from.

Comment: What are you talking about here?  Is this a website or a web app?  If it's a web app then you need to put them into html files with opening and closing style tags and includes with scriptlets.

Comment: go to: Network tab of your browser dev tools, select CSS then reload page and monitor which files will get by the browser, if 'stylesheet.css' is not there then the problem is about loading file, if it is and its color is red, then something is wrong about the file (just like its path), it the file has been correctly load (with status 200) then the problem can be about rewriting styles by another styles or stylesheets. in general, your question needs more detail and can have various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your path is correct.
2. Clean your cache (search shortcut for your browser), on google that's CTRL + F5.

Comment: tried both, didnt work

Comment: I don't see anything else. Frequently it's the path.